# Развернуть сайт ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Подскажите, как развернуть сайт на хосте, если он состоит из нескольких проектов?   прописывать путь запрещено на хосте, а каждый проект в отдельной папке получается

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

1. Указывайте относительные ссылки для
       связи между запускающимся проектом и
       дополнительными.
2. на сервер копируйте лишь view,
       используемые dll, content файлы и
       файлы, полученные при компиляции
       проекта (из release). Исходный Код
       вам не нужен.
3. вместо пункта 2 можно сделать файл
       установки (прямо в Visual Studio), и
       в процессе сборки установщика всё
       указать.

( Написал что знаю - пару раз всего заливал сайты на хостинг.)

Так же вам может быть полезна [Вот эта ссылка](http://microaspnet.blogspot.com/2012/10/asp.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать